# Intercepting sleep calls in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to intercept calls to sleep and sleep-like functions in C++? I'd love to be able to replace the implementation with a no-op or in the alternative, multiply the sleep time. I imagine this would aid in determining correctness of concurrent programs as well as identifying a source of flakiness in tests.

I'm operating on a gigantic codebase, so using a wrapper function would be less satisfactory. Maybe there's a way to use ptrace or the same techniques that programs like valgrind use to intercept malloc?

Comment: (i) Can you qualify "sleep"? (ii) When does it have to be done (what's wrong with e.g. `sed`) and why?

Comment: Typically one _mocks_ such things....

Comment: @black - The problem is more that there are thousands of developers in this codebase and I'd rather make this transparent to them. I only actually want to do this for a few special cases, it's not worth changing how that many people operate to make it happen.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yes, typically that would be the tool I reach for. Unfortunately that won't scale here.

Answer (score 6):

For gcc users there is a simple way to modify some calls to the libraries and link against own functions without changing the code itself.

if you have a snippet like:

```
... some stuff ...
AnyLibFunc();
... some stuff ...
```

you can advice the linker to use a wrapped method with the following line:

```
gcc program.c -Wl,-wrap,AnyLibFunc -o program
```

And you have to add your implementation of the wrapped func:

```
void __wrap_AnyLibFunc ()
{
    __real_AnyLibFunc(  ); // call the real function
}
```

In hope you are working on gcc environment!